# Contar secuencia ascendente

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio que recibe números del teclado hasta ingresar un 0 y muestre la cantidad de secuencias ascendentes.(Ejemplo: 15, 9, 5, 3, 4, 6 tiene solo 1 secuencia). Lo hice así:

```
int i;
int a[50];
int ascendente;
printf ("Ingrese números. Presione 0 para salir.\n");
while (a[i]!=0){
  for (i=0;i<50;i++){
    scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
    if (a[i]<a[i+1])
      ascendente++;
  }
}
printf ("Hay %d cantidad de secuencias ascendentes.\n", ascendente);
```

En ese caso, compara solo dos elementos de la secuencia. No sé cómo hacer para que considere una secuencia ascendente hasta que se ingrese un número inferior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu combo `while`/`for` va a mantener al usuario dentro del ciclo hasta que escriba un cero por teclado y eventualmente va a sobreescribir el array que defines con 50 indices.

La idea principal de tu algoritmo no difiere tanto de un algoritmo para ordenar arrays por lo que la solución inicial es tener todo el conjunto de datos antes de trabajar sobre el:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_ARR (50)

int main(void) {
  int Arr[MAX_ARR], Arrlen = 0, cant = 0, Asc = 0;
  printf("Llenar array (0 para terminar): \n");
  for (Arrlen = 0; Arrlen < MAX_ARR; Arrlen++) {
    printf("A[%d]: ", Arrlen + 1);

    scanf(" %d", (Arr + Arrlen));
    if (!Arr[Arrlen])
      break;
  }

  for (int i = 0; Arrlen && (i < Arrlen); i++) {
    if (Arr[i] < Arr[i + 1])
      cant++;
    else {
      if (cant) Asc++;
      cant = 0;
    }
  }

  printf("Cantidad de ascendentes: %d\n", Asc);
  return 0;
}
```

Anteriormente intentabas hacer todo dentro del mismo ciclo, cosa que es posible de una manera demasiado tediosa y que probablemente confunda a cualquier otro desarrollador, esta solución intenta separar ambos trabajos:

- Llenar el array.
- Operar en el array.

Si te fijas hay dos `for`, el primero es necesario para introducir los valores, el segundo es para comparar toodo el conjunto de datos mientras hayan elementos.

> He probado el programa de arriba y arroja los siguientes resultados:
>
> ```
> Llenar array (0 para terminar): 
> A[1]:  1
> A[2]:  2
> A[3]:  1
> A[4]:  2
> A[5]:  1
> A[6]:  2
> A[7]:  1
> A[8]:  2
> A[9]:  0
> Cantidad de ascendentes: 4
>
> Llenar array (0 para terminar): 
> A[1]:  1
> A[2]:  2
> A[3]:  3
> A[4]:  4
> A[5]:  5
> A[6]:  6
> A[7]:  0
> Cantidad de ascendentes: 1
>
> Llenar array (0 para terminar): 
> A[1]:  1
> A[2]:  2
> A[3]:  4
> A[4]:  1
> A[5]:  3
> A[6]:  5
> A[7]:  2
> A[8]:  0
> Cantidad de ascendentes: 2
> ```

[Aquí](https://repl.it/repls/TurbulentPastelIteration) te dejo un repl.it para que pruebes.

Saludos :)

Comment: Lo explicas muy claramente @NaCl. Gracias!!!!

Comment: Te quiero hacer una consulta:
1. Cuando usas el scanf para que guarde el entero en arr+Arrlen es lo mismo que poner arr[Arrlen]?
2. Es necesario poner el if (!Arr[Arrlen])? pregunto porque si está adentro del for, no va a parar cuando llegue a 50?

Comment: 1. No, en un array `Arr[Arrlen]` no es lo mismo que `Arr + Arrlen`, en el primero estas accediendo al valor, el segundo es _un_ equivalente de lo que haces: `&Arr[Arrlen]`. 2. El `if (!Arr[Arrlen])` es para saber si el valor del elemento es cero y se detendrá si llega a los 50 elementos o si el usuario pone un `0` antes de llegar a 50, técnicamente: `if (!Arr[Arrlen])` es lo mismo que `if (Arr[Arrlen] == 0)`

Comment: Y Arrlen && (i < Arrlen) qué significa?

Comment: Sería el equivalente de: `(Arrlen != 0) && (i < Arrlen)`, no es realmente necesario, es una vieja costumbre de trabajar con punteros, cuando `Arrlen != 0` significa que hay elementos, esa condición se convertiría en lo siguiente: `0 != 0 && 0 < 0` cuando `i` y `Arrlen` son `0`.

Comment: Al final, esa condición puede ser resumida a sólo `(i < Arrlen)`